# Why do I get a WM_MOUSELEAVE after enabling window?

Tags: c, winapi

After enabling a disabled child window, I try to turn mouse tracking on in `WM_ENABLE` only if mouse cursor is hovering over the window using `TrackMouseEvent()` with dwFlags of `TRACKMOUSEEVENT` structure set to `TME_LEAVE`. `TrackMouseEvent()` returns TRUE, but then right after calling it I get a `WM_MOUSELEAVE` message. This happens only under 2 conditions. With first condition, move cursor outside of child window, press Enter key to disable the window, then move cursor over the child window and press the Space key. With second condition, move the cursor over window, press Enter key to disable it, then before pressing the Space key move the cursor 1 pixel or more and then press the Space key. If you retest the second condition, but instead of moving cursor before you press the Space key, if you press the Space key right after you press the Enter key, mouse tracking is turned on properly. I've tried really hard to fix this but I've not been lucky so far. Can somebody please fix this code and explain why mouse tracking is being canceled when I'm trying to turn it on?

```
#include <windows.h>


const WCHAR g_szChildClassName[] = L"Childclass////";
HINSTANCE g_hInst;


LRESULT CALLBACK ChildProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static BOOL bMouseTracking = FALSE;

    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            HDC hdc;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            if(hdc)
            {
                HBRUSH hbr = CreateSolidBrush(bMouseTracking?RGB(255, 0, 0):RGB(0, 0, 255));
                if(hbr)
                {
                    FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, hbr);
                    DeleteObject(hbr);
                }
                EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            }
        }
        break;

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        if(!bMouseTracking) 
        {
            TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme = { 0 };
            tme.cbSize    = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
            tme.dwFlags   = TME_LEAVE;
            tme.hwndTrack = hwnd;
            bMouseTracking = TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
            InvalidateRect(hwnd, 0, TRUE);
        }
        break;

    case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
        bMouseTracking = FALSE;
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, 0, TRUE);
        break;

    case WM_ENABLE:
        if(wParam) 
        {
            RECT rc;
            if(GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc))
            {
                POINT pt;
                if(GetCursorPos(&pt))
                    if(PtInRect(&rc, pt)) 
                    {
                        TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme = { 0 };
                        tme.cbSize    = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
                        tme.dwFlags   = TME_LEAVE;
                        tme.hwndTrack = hwnd;
                        //TrackMouseEvent() posts WM_MOUSELEAVE if conditions 1 and 2 are met, even though I'm trying to turn 
                        //mouse tracking on and the cursor is over the child window. It doesn't make sense
                        //The problems is this piece of code right here /* bMouseTracking = TrackMouseEvent(&tme); */
                        //It should turn tracking on but it doesn't it cancels it even though WS_DISABLED has already been removed
                        //at this point
                        bMouseTracking = TrackMouseEvent(&tme); 
                        InvalidateRect(hwnd, 0, TRUE);
                    }
            }
        } else {
            if(bMouseTracking) { 
                ////////If you comment everything from here ...
                TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme = { 0 };
                tme.cbSize    = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
                tme.dwFlags   = TME_LEAVE | TME_CANCEL;
                tme.hwndTrack = hwnd;
                //if(TrackMouseEvent(&tme)) PostMessage(hwnd, WM_MOUSELEAVE, 0, 0); //Commented this line out to do things a bit differently with the same results  
                if(TrackMouseEvent(&tme)) { //If this succeeds it means mouse tracking was canceled
                    bMouseTracking = FALSE;
                    InvalidateRect(hwnd, 0, TRUE);
                }
                ////////all the way down to here the result is the same
                //If you comment everything in this block out then you have another problem which can be tested with this condition:
                //With window enabled move mouse over window, then press the ENTER key. The color should change 
                //from red to blue but it doesn't. It will change to blue though if you move the mouse 1 or more pixels after you've pressed the ENTER key
            }
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        bMouseTracking = FALSE;
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND hChild;

    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        hChild = CreateWindowEx(0, g_szChildClassName, 0, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 4, 4, 240, 80, hwnd, 0, g_hInst, 0);
        break;

    case WM_KEYDOWN:
             if(wParam == VK_SPACE)  EnableWindow(hChild, TRUE);
        else if(wParam == VK_RETURN) EnableWindow(hChild, FALSE);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default: 
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}


int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    const TCHAR szClassName[] = L"abccccccc";
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;

    SecureZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) return 0; //Register main window class

    SecureZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = ChildProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szChildClassName;
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) return 0; //Register child window class

    g_hInst = hInstance;
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, szClassName, L"Test", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 40, 40, 420, 200, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
    if(!hwnd) return 0;

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

EDIT: You can't see the cursor in the pictures cause I used screen capture and it doesn't capture the cursor. In the first picture the cursor is outside of the child window and in the second picture the cursor is inside of the child window

ENTER key pressed when cursor is outside of child window
[image]

SPACE key pressed after the ENTER key was previously pressed and cursor is hovering over child window
[image]

Comment: Maybe that's not so clear.  There is a certainly a bug in this code, the WM_ENABLE handler with wParam == 0 should *not* call TrackMouseEvent() on a disabled window and certainly not call PostMessage.  There is already a TrackMouseEvent() active, it automatically generates WM_MOUSELEAVE when the window gets disabled.  Do nothing.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm calling `TrackMouseEvent()` with `dwFlags` set to `TME_LEAVE | TME_CANCEL` to cancel mouse tracking. `TrackMouseEvent()` can be called to both set and cancel mouse tracking. If the mouse is being tracked, it will not be automatically canceled after the window is disabled. It will be canceled though if the mouse is moved 1 or more pixels after the window has been disabled. Even if I were to do nothing when `wParam == 0` the result is the same. Comment out everything in WM_ENABLE when wParam == 0 and see for yourself

Comment: Just do whatever you need to do so that you don't get *two* WM_MOUSELEAVE messages.

Comment: `WM_ENABLE` is sent while the window is still being enabled/disabled, so possibly `EnableWindow` does something to trigger `WM_MOUSELEAVE` after sending `WM_ENABLE`.  Instead of calling `TrackMouseEvent` directly in your `WM_ENABLE` handler, perhaps post a custom message to yourself and call `TrackMouseEvent` in its corresponding handler.

Comment: I tried posting `WM_MOUSEMOVE` but the system posts `WM_MOUSELEAVE` right after the `WM_MOUSEMOVE`. It seems like calling `TrackMouseEvent()` to track the mouse from `WM_ENABLE` when wParam != 0 doesn't work

Comment: Er, that's not what I suggested.  Did you try using a *custom* message and having that custom message handler call `TrackMouseEvent` instead?

Comment: What I don't understand is why you are complaining about receiving `WM_MOUSELEAVE`, when by your own admission, what you want to know is precisely this: when the mouse has left the window. That's exactly what `WM_MOUSELEAVE` is telling you, and `WM_MOUSELEAVE` exists precisely because mouse events are from that moment on going to be given to another window, so your window can't have them. So, you should be glad you are receiving `WM_MOUSELEAVE`. That's all you need to do your job. Without even invoking `TrackMouseEvent()` in the first place.

Comment: @jamesdlin I tried it and it still doesn't work. `WM_MOUSELEAVE` is posted last after the custom message handler calls `TrackMouseEvent()`

Comment: @MikeNakis I'm complaining because I get `WM_MOUSELEAVE` when the cursor is within the window. You're supposed to get `WM_MOUSELEAVE` when the cursor leaves the window. If you create a new project and try the first piece of code I posted you'll see exactly the problem I describe

Comment: @Rm32a yes, but that's likely a side-effect of using `TrackMouseEvent()` and doing it from within your `WM_ENABLE` handler.  Why don't you just write a `WM_MOUSELEAVE` handler and be finished?

Comment: @MikeNakis Did you even look at the first piece of code? There is a WM_MOUSELEAVE handler there. It sets bMouseTracking to FALSE and invalidates the window

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a shortcoming of the documentation or a bug in `TrackMouseEvent`, but it looks like `TrackMouseEvent` doesn't expect to be called within your `WM_ENABLE` handler.

To avoid that, try posting a message from WM_ENABLE and calling TrackMouseEvent from that:

```
case WM_ENABLE:
    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_USER, wParam, lParam);
    break;
case WM_USER:
    if(wParam) 
    {
        RECT rc;
        if(GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc))
        {
            POINT pt;
            if(GetCursorPos(&pt))
                if(PtInRect(&rc, pt)) 
                {
                    TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme = { 0 };
                    tme.cbSize    = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
                    tme.dwFlags   = TME_LEAVE;
                    tme.hwndTrack = hwnd;
                    //TrackMouseEvent() posts WM_MOUSELEAVE if conditions 1 and 2 are met, even though I'm trying to turn 
                    //mouse tracking on and the cursor is over the child window. It doesn't make sense
                    //The problems is this piece of code right here /* bMouseTracking = TrackMouseEvent(&tme); */
                    //It should turn tracking on but it doesn't it cancels it even though WS_DISABLED has already been removed
                    //at this point
                    bMouseTracking = TrackMouseEvent(&tme); 
                    InvalidateRect(hwnd, 0, TRUE);
                }
        }
    } else {
        if(bMouseTracking) { 
            ////////If you comment everything from here ...
            TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme = { 0 };
            tme.cbSize    = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
            tme.dwFlags   = TME_LEAVE | TME_CANCEL;
            tme.hwndTrack = hwnd;
            //if(TrackMouseEvent(&tme)) PostMessage(hwnd, WM_MOUSELEAVE, 0, 0); //Commented this line out to do things a bit differently with the same results  
            if(TrackMouseEvent(&tme)) { //If this succeeds it means mouse tracking was canceled
                bMouseTracking = FALSE;
                InvalidateRect(hwnd, 0, TRUE);
            }
            ////////all the way down to here the result is the same
            //If you comment everything in this block out then you have another problem which can be tested with this condition:
            //With window enabled move mouse over window, then press the ENTER key. The color should change 
            //from red to blue but it doesn't. It will change to blue though if you move the mouse 1 or more pixels after you've pressed the ENTER key
        }
    }
    break;
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. The system posts `WM_MOUSELEAVE` right after `WM_USER`